# Why is the order of importing files resolving a NameError?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have three files, one being the main file that needs to be run, and the other two contain utility functions, as follows. All the files are in the same directory and I am running it on PyCharm.

```py
# delta_plots.py - This is the main file
...
from delta_plots_utility_1 import *
from delta_plots_utility_2 import *
...

def print_parameter_header(params, flag):
    batch_size, epochs, lr = params[0], params[1], params[2]
    print("{} - Batch size: {}, Epochs: {}, Learning rate: {}".
         format(flag.upper(), batch_size, epochs, lr))
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # call the utility functions based on a condition
    if (condition1):
        utility_function_1()
    elif (condition2):
        utility_function_2()
```

```py
# delta_plots_utility_1.py - Utility file 1

# this import statement is to import the print_parameter_header() function 
# from the main file
from plot_delta_mp import *

def utility_function_1():
    # this function makes a call to the print_parameter_header() function
    ...
    print_parameter_header(params, flag)
    ...
```

```py
# delta_plots_utility_2.py - Utility file 2

from plot_delta_mp import *

def utility_function_2():
    # this function also makes a call to the print_parameter_header() function
    ...
    print_parameter_header(params, flag)
    ...
```

The problem is when in the main file, if *condition1* is true, then I am forced to put the import statement for utility file 1 before the import statement for utility file 2, and vice versa.

Otherwise, I get the following error:
`NameError: name 'print_parameter_header' is not defined`

I also tried importing the files as modules and then accessing the function as `module.print_parameter_header()`, but that does not help either.

I had the following questions regarding this:

1. From what I understand, the order of the import statements is not important. So why is this happening? Why does changing the order resolve the error?
2. Could this be because of the loop-like importing? Since I am importing the main file in the utility functions too.
3. If yes, then is it okay to define `print_parameter_header()` in the utility files? Although it would be redundant, is that a good practice?

Comment: The fact that your two utility modules is using a function that isn't supplied either locally or via an explicit import is a bit sketchy.

Comment: You have circular dependencies. Try putting common functions (`print_parameter_header`) in e.g. common.py and importing that into both utility scripts.

Comment: I had thought of it too. But I did not want to make an extra file for just one function. Turns out I had more functions that I could put in it so it's working now. Good suggestion! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all of your issues come from that initial misunderstanding: "From what I understand, the order of the import statements is not important."

In python, an import statement

- can happen anywhere in the code (not necessarily at the beginning), so if you enter into circular dependency issues it might be a good idea to import the latest possible if you have no other design choice
- creates symbols in the code. So `from xxx import a` will create variable `a` locally, just like writing `a = 0`. It is exactly the same.

So maybe a good solution for you would be to stop using `from <xxx> import *` or `import <xxx>`, which both import *all* symbols from the other module, but to import selected symbols in precisely controlled places. Such as `from <xxx> import a, b` and later in your code `from <xxx> import c`.

Sorry for not taking the time to adapt the above answer to your precise code example, but hopefully you'll get the idea.